Maximum Number of Student, TItu 102 Combinatorial Problem (Additional Problem)
I already found some interesting bounding. I think the answer will be 1899, but I don't find any proof until now. If $n\geq1900$ by the configuration of 55 schools with 34 students, and 1 school with 30 students, will need more than 11 row.
Also I found that, if we want $n$ to be maximum then, $n$ should be in the interval of [1873,1899], and I can't prove that 1899 is max.
Can anyone give me the solution ?

(Not quite an exact duplicate, but you can tweak it) This question is similar to: Determine minimum number of rows to be reserved.. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your posted question is somewhat confusing.
If is given that there are at least $~11 \times 199 = 2189~$ different schools that might send students to the game, then you could (for example) have each school send 1 person.  Then, all $~2189~$ students could be seated.

So, the problem becomes pointless unless there is a limit to the number of schools that might send students to the game.
Reverse-engineering your (somewhat garbled) presentation of the question, it seems that there are $~55~$ schools that might send students to the game.  So this response will be based on that (possibly erroneous) assumption.
This means that the maximum number of students that might be sent is
$$55 \times 39 = 2145.$$
If there are exactly $~2145~$ students sent from exactly $~55~$ schools, then, since $~5 \times 39 < 199,~$ and since $~5 \times 11 = 55,~$ all $~2145~$ students can be satisfactorily seated.
That is, you assign $~5~$ schools to each row, capitalizing on the fact that $~5 \times 11 = 55.$
Then, since $~5 \times 39 < 199,~$ each row can accommodate $~5~$ different schools, with each school sending $~39~$ students.

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
The assumption of $~55~$ schools resulted in $~4~$ wasted seats per row.
If the assumption is changed to $~66~$ schools, then you could assign $~6~$ schools to each row, rather than $~5~$ schools.
Then, in each row, the $~6$-th school could send exactly $~4~$ students.
Then, there are no wasted seats, so you end up satisfactorily accommodating  $~2189~$ students.

Hello, it doesn't matter there are how many schools, I mean you can create the worst case (need the greatest amount of seats), as example, 1990 students can be seated by only 12 rows, and 13 rows becomes unefficient.

@LimZhaoSen Really?  Did you find an analytical or algebraic error anywhere in my response?  If so, which line in my response has the error?  Failing that, my response demonstrates that the number of schools involved is relevant and that if $~55~$ schools send $~39~$ students each, all of the students can be seated in only $~11~$ rows.

Your argument is not wrong, but not answered the question. I told you to try find the worst case, if there are 1990 students, there exist a worst case such that at least 12 rows needed. So if $n\geq 1990$ must be wrong.

@LimZhaoSen I am sorry, but the question that you posted was so garbled, that I took my best guess as to what your intent was.

@LimZhaoSen For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

@LimZhaoSen Re the linked article, I suggest that you focus on the portions re [1] Not using an image. [2] Showing work. [3] Striving to make it impossible for anyone to be in any way confused about what you are asking.

Sorry for the ambiguous of this problem, this problem is from a book, which already used for years by math olympiad student, and before the book got published, the quality control must have checked all ambiguous statement...

@user2661923 I disagree with "the question that you posted was so garbled". OP asked for a solution to the problem, and stated that they have shown that the max is $ \leq 1899$ via constructing a counter example, and claim (no proof in post) that the maximum is in the interval $[1873, 1899]$. $\quad$ You are making unwarranted assumptions about the number of schools. The solution needs to apply to every possible scenario, not just specific ones that you looked at.

@CalvinLin I just read the linked problem, which I find very clear. I am baffled that you would not regard the OP's posting as garbled. How I was supposed to infer the OP's intent from the OP's posted question is beyond me.
